# Only part of script is executing on startup

Tags: boot

I have a script (`start_probing.sh`) in `/etc/init.d` which successfully runs on startup, however, when I call another script (`adapter_scan.sh`) from within it does not run. Though, when I manually run `start_probing.sh` everything runs normally. In `start_probing.sh` I wait some time before executing `adapter_scan.sh` to ensure the `wlan1` interface is ready, though to no avail. Any suggestions?

Here are the codes for both scripts:

**start_probing.sh**:

```
echo $(date) >> /home/pi/reboot.txt  
sleep 1m && watch -n 20 sudo /home/pi/adapter_scan.sh & PROC=$! ; sleep 120s ; KILL $PROC
```

**adapter_scan.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash  
fname="ap_data.txt"
save_path="/home/pi/data/$fname"  
interface="wlan1"  

echo "[x] $(date):" >> $save_path  
sudo iwlist $interface scanning |\  
egrep "Signal level|ESSID" |\  
sed -e "s/\"ESSID://" |\  
sed 's/^.*Signal/Signal/' |\  
 paste -s -d' \n' |\  
  sed -e 's/\(Signal\|level=\)//g' |\  
   sed -e 's/^[ \tESSID:]*//' |\  
    sort >> $save_path  
     echo "~" >> $save_path  
      cat $save_path
```

The problem is that the `ap_data.txt` file is never created. What am I missing?

**Update**
So it seems I am a fool. [This](https://github.com/OpenLabTools/OpenLabTools/wiki/Launching-bash-scripts-at-startup) post made me realize that having my script executing on login (rather than on startup which should be taken quite seriously) is a far more appropriate approach. Simply placing `sh .../adapter_scan.sh` in my `~/.profile` accomplished exactly what I was after.

Comment: Does `/home/pi/data/` exist? Is `/home` mounted at the time the script run? Does `/home/pi/` need to be decrypted? Are scripts in `/etc/init.d` supposed to be [run by `systemd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/233468/108618) or what?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski the `/home/pi/` directory seems to not be the issue since the reboot.txt file contains the proper $(date). However one thing to note that I haven't mentioned is that I created the soft link to `start_probing.sh` within `/etc/init.d/rc3.d`, could this impact the script?

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you have the X (execute) bit set on the script you're trying to run for the user privilege that needs it.

Comment: The script did indeed have the execute permission. I found out by redirecting stderr that my issue was that I was calling the script during startup when a bash process was likely not available. Thanks for your reply though, @Ddirk!